# tabular vertical align based on lowest line in a cell, not on the base line

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to make an enumeration that looks like this

```
1.   This is some very long
     sentence that might need
     several lines. Does the
     next cell line up with 
     the last line of this
     paragraph?                 yes/no

2.   Did it work again?         yes/no
```

It seems that there is no easy way to do this in LaTeX. If I could just have a tabu(lar(x)) environment that works like this that would be great. But ideally I would like to have something like this with the output above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\yesno}[1]
{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}b{.7\linewidth}b{.3\linewidth}@{}}
        #1 & yes/no
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \yesno{\lipsum*[1]}
        \item \yesno{\lipsum*[1]}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here I would like to give an extra option to the tabular environment that says that it has to align it's most upper line with the rest. Now I know there are some problems with putting a table inside an enumeration, so I don't mind if I have to make my own environment with my own enumeration. The hardest part is to get the alignment the way I want it.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to have some columns top-aligned and some columns bottom-aligned. The author of [[this paper](http://cau.ac.kr/~mhhgtx/Resources/TableTricks.pdf)] says (page 5) that "`p{}`
`m{}` and `b{}` formats cannot be successfully mixed in the same table", though he doesn't explain why. [Herbert seems to have found a way round that though.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115225/25356)

Comment: I don't agree with the paper. You can mix these formats, the only problem is that the alignment is counter intuitive. It says where the paragraph goes with respect to the baseline and not with respect to cell. This is good for formulas but not really for tables in general (in my opinion). It seems like my golden rule (if it's easy in MS Word and hard in LaTeX, you're about to do something stupid) doesn't really work this time. @Herbert's solution works in this case, but unfortunately not in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{yesno}
\newcommand*\textdemo{This is some text to demonstrate the behaviour of
  what I want.}
\newenvironment{YesNo}
  {\setcounter{yesno}{0}\tabularx{0.7\linewidth}
    {@{}>{\stepcounter{yesno}\theyesno.}r X @{}}}
  {\endtabularx}

\newcommand\yesno[1]{ & #1 %\hrulefill% only for demo to see the allignment
  \hfill\rlap{\hspace{\tabcolsep}yes/no} \\} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{YesNo}
        \yesno{\textdemo}
        \yesno{\textdemo \textdemo}
        \yesno{\textdemo}
    \end{YesNo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Circle yes three times! I'll google around a bit to figure out what exactly is going on and how I can extend it to the slightly more complex environment I'm going (but didn't ask) for. Thanks a lot!